# VueJS $refs is undefined after :src change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having a problem with $refs in VueJS 3, I have 3 images with a bind on :src, I then use a method that changes the value in :src but the $refs is then undefined. The EventListener animationend works fine because the console error shows up at the end of the animation.

Here's the code

```
<img :src="mainImg" class="illustration" @click="switchImg">
                <div class="glitch_effect" ref="glitchEffect">
                    <img :src="mainImg" class="glitch-one" ref="glitchOne">
                    <img :src="mainImg" class="glitch-two" ref="glitchTwo">
                </div>
```

And the js

```
export default {
    name: "illustration",
    data() {
        return {
            mainImg: 'https://www.mathieubarco.com/assets/img/sing_for_me.jpg',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        switchImg() {

            this.mainImg = "https://www.mathieubarco.com/assets/img/regina_final.jpg"
            // these $refs are defined and add the class
            this.$refs.glitchOne.classList.add('glitch-active');
            this.$refs.glitchTwo.classList.add('glitch-active');
            this.$refs.glitchEffect.classList.add('glitch-active');

            this.$refs.glitchOne.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
                // these $refs are undifined and don't remove the class
                this.$refs.glitchOne.classList.remove('glitch-active')
                this.$refs.glitchTwo.classList.remove('glitch-active')
                this.$refs.glitchEffect.classList.remove('glitch-active')
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `() => {}` not `function () {}` here `this.$refs.glitchOne.addEventListener("animationend", function () {`